# get In-Reply-To value from InternetMessageHeader in outlook graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to use the MS graph API to get the In-Reply-To message header without having to return the entire header (internetMessageHeaders). I already get several properties (such as bccRecipients, from, id) which are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

I've seen [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103388/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-rfc-2822-or-any-headers-from-an-email-with-the) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187835/microsoft-graph-api-get-internetmessageheaders-issue-missing-certain-headers) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103388/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-rfc-2822-or-any-headers-from-an-email-with-the) asking this and they point to using SingleValueExtendedProperties/internetMessageHeaders with a `$filter` clause. I've tried this and it appears to only work with properties which are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

This is what I've tried all give a 404 error (i've checked the the In-Reply-To header is present on the actual message)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/MSG_ID?
$select=Subject,internetMessageId,from,id,bccRecipients,
SingleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=In-Reply-To eq 'String 0x007D')
```

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/MSG_ID?
$select=Subject,internetMessageId,from,id,bccRecipients,
internetMessageHeaders&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=In-Reply-To eq 'String 0x007D')
```

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/MSG_ID?
$select=Subject,internetMessageId,from,id,bccRecipients,
internetMessageHeaders&$expand=internetMessageHeaders($filter=In-Reply-To eq 'String 0x007D')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to request `PR_IN_REPLY_TO_ID` MAPI property (`0x1042001F`)

```
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x1042')
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what I was doing wrong now. I'm not familiar with MAPI, could you link to where I can find the associated values? Also you specify two things 0x1042001F and 0x1042, only 0x1042 works, what is 0x1042001F for?

Comment: MAPI property tags have two parts - the id (0x1042) and and the property type (0x001F = PT_UNICODE). You can see the property tags and property values in in OutlookSpy (https://www.dimastr.com/outspy, click IMessage button). You can also construct Graph queries from property tags - click Message button on the Graph group on OutlookSpy ribbon, click "Query Parameters", then the button next to the $expand checkbox.

Comment: Here is the doc to the 0x1042: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaginreplytoid-canonical-property